# Azure B2C - Can't create new account with an old email

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have an Azure B2C user flow where I'm allowing my users to change their emails. I'm running a test case where:

1. A user logs in with their account.
2. The user changes the email address on their account to a new email.
3. The user comes back in and tries to create a new account with the old email.

I have part 3 in two steps - the first one registers their email address and verifies the email doesn't already exist, and the second part allows them to enter a password for their account and creates the account.

Part 1 is fine: It checks b2c, says the user doesn't exist, and continues.
But in Part 2, when I go to create the account, it's coming back with an error that the user already exists.

If I check for them in my B2C users, they're not there; same if I search from the graph API. The checks say they don't exist. But I can't reuse that email later.

What I'm wondering is - I've heard of some systems where once an email is registered to an account, it's locked in there; even if you change it, the original email will still be associated to it. It looks like that might be what's happening here. But is that right? Or should I be able to create new accounts with those old emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. The issue is that when the user creates their account, it updates both the Sign In Email and the Mail field - the mail field is used so that we always have them tied to an address for MFA that can be changed from the B2C backend portal.

Problem is when the Mail address gets updated, it also updates the ProxyAddresses field. The ProxyAddresses stores all the emails they've had, and is unique - so when we then try to create a new user with that email, it gets rejected because some other user already has the email address in their own ProxyAddresses list.

As far as I can tell there's no way to disable ProxyAddresses, so the only workaround seems to be to not use the Mail field - we'll need to make a custom solution for it to update a user's email address through an API if we ever need to change their MFA address manually.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already have this email in the [Identity array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes#identities-attribute) of a user.

Did you check that?

Comment: Took a look and it's not in there - just the new email address and the userPrincipalName. The old email isn't in there, but it's still acting like it is (I can't create a new account with it, and that's the only account that's able to change back into it)